# Send message with a event link to selected facebook friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

My event website in PHP needs "invite selected facebook friends" with a short message and an event link. But after lots of search, I found "Facebook returns the friends lists who uses this application". I tried few steps and got the same.

Is there any other option to do this ?

Comment: As per new changes only those friends can be listed who are using same app. You may check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: Is there any other option available to do this ?

Comment: Well before 3-4 days, I was searching for the same. But I have seen that kaypay is getting complete friend list. Might be they have tie up with facebook. Because when I tried same code, I still get the friendlist those using same app only.

Comment: Use the send or share dialog

Comment: I tried send message but it doesn't allow to track the recipients. Send message tried is: http://w3lessons.info/2012/10/15/inviting-facebook-friends-to-your-website-using-javascript-sdk/